# Get all URL's from Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I am using Tastypie with Django and want to get a list of all URL's accessible via the api, is there a method oder URL I can call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried just querying the root-endpoint of your API and navgating from there?

Possibly that is something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/?format=json
```

Comment: Kids, please try this at home. ;-)